# Extract a word in a paragraph using regex in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a paragraph and I need to extract a word from it.

```
Attention:
Investigator: O'Toole, Tim  
Suspect Name:
Ezekiel, David

Account Number:
4323232
```

DEsired output:

```
Ezekiel, David
```

What I tried:

```
regexp_extract([Case_Desc],'Name : (.+)Account')
```

The above regex worked in tableau but for some reasons, toad for Oracle does not support this. Any help on this is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your query

Comment: regexp_extract([Case_Desc],'Name : (.+)Account')

Case_Desc is the column name

Comment: Add your code to the question itself by using [Edit].

Answer (score 1):

One option would be using `regexp_substr()` with `ltrim()`

```
with t(str) as
(
 select 'Attention:
Investigator: O''Toole, Tim  
Suspect Name:
Ezekiel, David

Account Number:
4323232' from dual 
)
select ltrim(regexp_substr(str,'\e:[^\Account]+'),'e:') as "Result String" 
  from t;

Result String
---------------
Ezekiel, David
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/GYABET60949)</kbd>

*By the way, there's no function called `regexp_extract()` in Oracle.*

Answer (score 1):

Option which uses `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination, which selects values that are written between "Suspect Name:" and "Account Number" (mind the letter case; if it differs, applying `lower` or `upper` function might help).

```
SQL> select
  2    trim(
  3      substr(str,
  4             instr(str, 'Suspect Name:') + 14,
  5             instr(str, 'Account Number') - instr(str, 'Suspect Name:') - 14
  6            )) result
  7  from t;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ezekiel, David
```